# java online compiler with different versions

Tags: java

I am looking for an online compiler where it is supported to choose version of java runtime.

Because I want to try things that was not available in older versions of java to feel the difference.

Is there such compilers?

Comment: http://ideone.com/, You can choose two of Java 7 versions. But no older versions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com is for me the best online compiler, it supports up to 40 languages and has almost no restrictions, i think you can choose between a couple of Java versions, not sure which ones.